# Macro step counter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a simple VBA step counter that sums up a column until the column adds up to a positive number. Essentially these are cash flows that calculate when the cash becomes break even. I am simply trying to add the cells starting from Z13 until the Total becomes a positive number(the first year of cashflows are negative). I am getting an

> "Object required"

error when I run this code:

```
Sub Breakeven()

Dim Total As Long
Dim StepCounter As Integer


Total = Range("z13").Value
Set StepCounter = 14

If Total < 0 Then

Total = Total + CashFlows.Cells(Z, StepCounter).Value
StepCounter = StepCounter + 1

End If

MsgBox "The breakeven is " & Total

End Sub
```

Please help!

Comment: You can't `Set` an `Integer` because that's not an object.  Remove the `Set` keyword.

Comment: also I believe `CashFlows.Cells(Z, StepCounter).Value` should be `CashFlows.range("Z" & StepCounter).Value` (unless `Z` is a variable with an integer value assigned elsewhere in your code)

Comment: Thanks! but I still get an object required error when I do that.

Comment: It would be helpful to state the line which errors.

Comment: I can F8 until I get to :StepCounter = StepCounter + 1

Comment: "I can F8 until I get to `StepCounter = StepCounter + 1`" - only if you skip the line that `Set`-assigns an `Integer` value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a **loop**:

Consider:

```
Sub Breakeven()
    Dim Total As Long
    Dim StepCounter As Integer
    Dim CashFlows As Worksheet
    Set CashFlows = ActiveSheet


    Total = Range("z13").Value
    StepCounter = 14

    While Total < 0
            Total = Total + CashFlows.Cells(StepCounter, "Z").Value
            StepCounter = StepCounter + 1
    Wend
    MsgBox "The breakeven is " & Total

End Sub
```

**NOTES:**

1. we defined a `worksheet` object and `Set` it
2. we created a `While` loop *(because `IF` will not loop by itself)*
3. we reversed the arguments in `Cells()`
4. we replaced the variable `Z` with the string constant
5. we removed the `Set` for `StepCounter`

Comment: Why advocate the depreciated `While Wend`?  Really should be using `Do Loop`

Comment: @chrisneilsen  Thank you chris..................I trust your judgement on this and will avoid `While` in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can *collapse* the code to this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim StepCounter As Long

    Do
        StepCounter  = StepCounter + 1
    Loop While WorkSheetFunction.Sum(Range("Z13").Resize(StepCounter) ) < 0
    MsgBox "The breakeven is " & WorkSheetFunction.Sum(Range("Z13").Resize(StepCounter) )
End Sub
```